# Is there a way to roll back an unapproved edit?

Tags: support

After some reflection, I realized that the clarification made in an edit is not actually true, so I wish to retract my edit and not bother anyone else with reviewing it.  Is this possible?

Comment: You may leave a comment, such reviewers can see it. There's no way I'm aware of though.

Comment: It's not. However, it's completed in review now and ended up rejected...

Comment: Ah well, thanks for the info, will keep that in mind.

Comment: It's somewhat bizarre that the dupe has an indistinct answer, but yes, it can stand.  Maybe this one should be deleted entirely..  What's the meta way?